# What is a topological supplement?

Tags: analysis, banach-spaces, topological-vector-spaces

In the book "Calculus Without Derivatives" written by Jean-Paul Penot there's the following theorem:

> **THEOREM:** Let $X$ and $Z$ be Banach spaces, let $W$ be an open subset of $X$, and let $g:W\to Z$ be a map of class $C^k$ with
> $k\geq 1$ such that for some $a\in W$ the map $Dg(a)$ is surjective
> and its kernel $N$ has a **topological supplement** $M$ in $X$. Then
> there exist an open neighborhood $U$ of $a$ in $W$ and a
> diffeomorphism $\varphi$ of class $C^k$ from $U$ onto a neighborhood
> $V$ of $(0, g(a))$ in $N\times Z$ such that $\varphi (a)=(0,g(a))$ and
> $g|_U=p\circ \varphi$ where $p$ is the canonical projection from
> $N\times Z$ onto $Z$.

**My question is:** in the context of the previous theorem, what does it mean to say that $N:=\ker Dg(a)$ has a topological supplement $M$ in $X$?

Thank you for your attention!

Comment: it means a closed subspace $M$ in $X$ such that $M\cap N=\{0\}$ and $M+N=X$. i.e so that we can write $X=M\oplus N$ as an internal direct sum, but now we add in the extra closedness assumption so that the direct-sum induced projections $P_M:X\to M$ and $P_N:X\to N$ are continuous surjections and so that the natural map $X=M\oplus N\to M\times X$ is a Banach-space isomorphism (i.e a continuous linear map with a continuous linear inverse).

Comment: ^ sorry typo, it should have been $X=M\oplus N\to M\times N$ (where the $\oplus$ on the LHS means an internal direct sum).

Comment: @peek-a-boo Just to be sure: we say that a subspace $N\subseteq X$ has a topological supplement $M\subseteq X$ if $X=N\oplus M$ and $M$ is a closed subspace, right?

Comment: usually we require $N$ to also be closed if I'm not mistaken, but since in your case $N$ is the kernel of a continuous linear map, this is automatically satisfied. btw, you should note that in this context (i.e when dealing with Banach spaces) people often write $X=M\oplus N$ to mean "$M,N$ are closed and their sum is direct in the linear algebra sense", so the closedness condition is implied in their terminology/notation (another term for "supplement" you may see is also "complement").